# How does React's useRef do to make it's return value ignore dependency warnings?

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

For example, consider the following code :

```
const useCustomRef = initialValue => useRef(initialValue);

const CustomComponent = () => {
  const ref1 = useRef();
  const ref2 = useCustomRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref2.current.otherRef = ref1.current;
  }, []);
  
  return <div>Ref test</div>;
};
```

*(**Note:** Nevermind the silliness, here, this is only to make point.)*

Now, importing (and rendering) this dummy component in an app running with [`react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) will print in the console :

```
path/to/dummy/component.jsx
Line 70:7:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'ref2'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Is that warning built-in, or is it possible to specify a hooks' immutable properties?

For example, certain hooks return immutable and immutable properties, like :

```
const ref = useRef();                              // immutable
const handleCallback = useCallback(() => {}, []);  // mutable
const [ value, setValue ] = useState();            // mutable, immutable
const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(...);       // mutable, immutable
...
```

So, can a user-defined hook define the same properties so that they are not [required as dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html)? I find it annoying to implement custom hooks returning immutable properties that are, then, required as dependencies while they would not otherwise (like for `ref2` in the example above).

Comment: Would https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#advanced-configuration help?

Comment: @AKX if I'm not mistaken, this only allows the Linter to *check* (i.e. validate) for dependencies, it does not solve the problem described, here.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm sorry, I just skimmed a little too hard there.

Comment: It looks like there's no extension point for that in `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, [it just has "tribal knowledge" about which values are guaranteed stable](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4298ddbc56a711cecfa672ec8ac60c94a02c9380/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js#L203-L273)...

Comment: @AKX interesting. The code is actually clean enough to support custom hooks. Good catch!